# How to deal with empty array to be sent as json in swift?

Tags: swift, swift5, codable, decodable, encodable

I'm trying to encode data but struggling to deal with empty array with no type as the API's I am working with needs me to send **[]** if there is no entry.

```
[
    {
        "RequestId": "5B6E36D9-8759-41BB-A0C0-EDFB116DFBB7",
        "DataSources": ["5B6E36D9-8759-41BB-A0C0-EDFB116DFBB7"],
        "GroupBy": [],
        "Filters": []
    }
]
```

above is the object json which I have to send.

```
struct ResponseElement: Encodable {
    let requestID: String
    let dataSources: [String]
    let groupBy: []
    let filters: []

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case requestID = "RequestId"
        case dataSources = "DataSources"
        case groupBy = "GroupBy"
        case filters = "Filters"
    }
}

let data = ResponseElement(requestID: "5B6E36D9-8759-41BB-A0C0-EDFB116DFBB7",
                           dataSources: ["5B6E36D9-8759-41BB-A0C0-EDFB116DFBB7", ["5B6E36D9-8759-41BB-A0C0-EDFB116DFBB7]"],
                           groupBy: [],
                           filters: [])

let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()
let data = try! jsonEncoder.encode(data)
```

please note while creating data variable I have to pass **groupBy, filters** as empty array **[]**, I have tried with [nil] which goes as [null] after encoding but it doesn't work in my case, it has to be **[]**

how do I solve this please?

Comment: on the cases where the server does send down values for `groupBy` and `filters`, what kind of values are they? are they a list of integers? strings?

Comment: I have to send down values to the server and the values are strings, so its array of strings. and when I am not sending anything in that case it has to be empty.

Answer (score 3):

If you know that the array will always be empty, the type of that is `[Never]`. A `Never` is a type that cannot be instantiated, so this array is necessarily empty.

Unfortunately, `Never` does not conform to Encodable. It should. It should conform to every protocol automatically (that would make Never a "bottom type," which is a good feature in a type system). That said, it's straightforward to provide the conformance:

```
extension Never: Encodable {
    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        // This line of code can never, ever run. It's impossible to
        // create a Never, so it's impossible to run its instance methods.
        fatalError()
    }
}

struct ResponseElement: Encodable {
    let requestID: String
    let dataSources: [String]
    let groupBy: [Never]
    let filters: [Never]

    ...
}
```

You may rightly feel uncomfortable extending a stdlib type to conform with a stdlib protocol. This is kind of fragile, since stdlib might create the conformance in the future, or some other package might do it, and  there'd be a conflict. So you can do this explicitly by creating a type of your own that encodes an empty unkeyed container:

```
struct EmptyArray: Encodable {
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        encoder.unkeyedContainer()
    }
}

struct ResponseElement: Encodable {
    let requestID: String
    let dataSources: [String]
    let groupBy: EmptyArray
    let filters: EmptyArray
    ...
}
```

And finally, you can perform the encoding by hand and get rid of the unnecessary properties (this is how I'd do it myself):

```
struct ResponseElement: Encodable {
    let requestID: String
    let dataSources: [String]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case requestID = "RequestId"
        case dataSources = "DataSources"
        case groupBy = "GroupBy"
        case filters = "Filters"
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(requestID, forKey: .requestID)
        try container.encode(dataSources, forKey: .dataSources)
        container.nestedUnkeyedContainer(forKey: .groupBy)
        container.nestedUnkeyedContainer(forKey: .filters )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is just for encoding data and you never have to provide anything for this properties you could use any type you want for your property:

e.g.

```
struct ResponseElement: Encodable {
    let requestID: String
    let dataSources: [String]
    let groupBy: [String] = []
    let filters: [String] = []

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case requestID = "RequestId"
        case dataSources = "DataSources"
        case groupBy = "GroupBy"
        case filters = "Filters"
    }
}
```

Result:

```
{
    "RequestId": "1",
    "GroupBy": [],
    "Filters": [],
    "DataSources": [
        "1",
        "2"
    ]
}
```